# What is the purpose of Boost::Fusion::Pair?

Tags: boost

It makes a key-value pair of a datatype and a value, which does not seem to have any practical value. One could do the same by passing a typename as the key in a normal pair. Is there some optimization or efficiency-related reason this datatype exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you the ability to create a compile time map which maps a type to a value: `boost::fusion::map`. This is an optimization over runtime maps because the mappings are done at compile time (though perhaps not a huge one because the maps are generally very small.)